# Linking an option in the menustrip to an image similar to a MessageBox.Show

Tags: c#

total newbie to C#, working on my final project for my intro class. Anyways, I am doing an online ordering form for a restaurant. In my menustrip, I have an option "Menu" (the actual restaurant's menu). I am going to scan a copy of the actual menu and import it into the resources, and when the user clicks "Menu", I'd like the picture to pop up similar to how a MessageBox does, and incorporate an "OK" button into it to exit. Is this possible?

```
private void viewFullMenuToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ????  PictureBox1 = Properties.Resources.Menu.jpg;
}
```

I know this is wrong. Any suggestions? Am I on the right track? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not write your own form that has a PictureBox and a button at the bottom. Put OK text on the button and close the dialog once it is clicked

Here is the [Picture Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You would then set the Image property on the PictureBox.

```
PictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Menu.jpg;
```